# Finding a Cycle in a Linked List

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, floyd-cycle-finding

I'm currently working with Floyd's Cycle Finding Algorithm for a question that asks me to detect if a singly linked list contains a *cycle*.. I understand the **Tortoise and Hare** approach but am somewhat confused regarding its implementation. There have been several posts about this algorithm but never that targets this aspect of the question.

```
public class Solution {
public boolean hasCycle(ListNode head) {
    
    ListNode slow = head;
    ListNode fast = head; 
    
    while(fast != null) {
        fast = fast.next.next; 
        slow = slow.next; 
        
        if(fast == slow)
            return true; 
    }
    return false;   
}
```

The only error in my code is that in my while-loop condition, I should have

```
while(fast != null && fast.next != null)
```

Instead of..

```
while(fast != null)
```

however, the latter while-loop condition makes more sense to me. I acknowledge that the correct implementation is simply assessing whether a particular node exists, and whether or not that node has a successor. However, if we simply check for `while(fast != null)` - wouldn't that suffice? After all, if `fast = null`, why bother to check `fast.next` anyways? Could there ever be a case where `fast = null` *and a cycle exists*? No, right? The standard implementation to judge whether we've reached the end of a linked list is: `while(current != null)` - why can't we do that here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> However, if we simply check for `while(fast != null)` - wouldn't that suffice?

No.

If you don't check that `fast.next` is not `null`, then when you do `fast.next.next`, you could get a `NullPointerException`.

(It depends on whether the number of elements in a cycle-free list is odd or even.)

Of course, you *could* move the `fast.next != null` into the loop ... but that is just rearranging the code.  The effect will be the same.

Comment: Hey - thanks for your response! I guess the take-away argument here is that I should check if fast.next.next actually exists before doing fast = fast.next.next ... so, I could try doing if(fast.next.next != null) { fast = fast.next.next; } ... however, you're advising me to check if fast.next != null instead of fast.next.next != null.. If I were at the second to last node, then fast.next may very well exist, but fast.next.next would not, leaving me with same null-pointer exception.. thoughts?

Comment: I am advising that you need to test `fast` AND `fast.next`.  You don't need to check `fast.next.next` because that will be tested in the following loop iteration ... after `fast` has been assigned the value of `fast.next.next`.  My advice is to stop asking us to explain.  Go get a piece of paper and a pencil and [hand execute](https://www.programming4beginners.com/tutorial/chapter04/execution-by-hand) the code until you *understand* what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You have the `fast = fast.next.next;` for which you need to have the null check of `fast.next` otherwise your code can throw null pointer exception.

You can change

```
fast = fast.next.next;
```

to

```
if(fast.next != null) fast = fast.next.next;
else break;
```

You can avoid an extra line of code by keeping this check at the loop entry itself.

Answer (score 0):

*Try a dry run of your code with **odd** number of elements say 5 and no cycle.*

Observe what happens when **`fast`** reaches the end of the list.

Comment: Hey - thanks for your response! I guess the take-away argument here is that I should check if fast.next.next actually exists before doing fast = fast.next.next ... so, I could try doing if(fast.next.next != null) { fast = fast.next.next; } ... however, you're advising me to check if fast.next != null instead of fast.next.next != null.. If I were at the second to last node, then fast.next may very well exist, but fast.next.next would not, leaving me with same null-pointer exception.. thoughts?

Comment: you should check for fast && fast.next and you shall never encounter NULL pointer exception. Try doing a dry run for number of nodes both even and odd say 6 and 7.